# Why does Javascript not perform the expected operation here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make a website in which I can place these NATO units on a map. It's all been going well so far until I started to work on the zoom function. The goal is to zoom the map canvas by a constant factor of either 2 or 0.5 and all of the units would retain their center position in relation to the map. However, these units will all remain the same size due to the inability to see small units.

I am currently having difficulties understanding why the zoom doesn't currently work. A quick run through the website reveals some major flaws. I suspect it has to do something with these two lines, lines 177 and 178 of the zoom(level) function in draw.js:

```
draggableElementsA[i].style.top = (draggableElementsA[i].getBoundingClientRect().top + (draggableElementsA[i].getBoundingClientRect().height / 2) - c1) * level - (draggableElementsA[i].getBoundingClientRect().height / 2) + canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
draggableElementsA[i].style.left = (draggableElementsA[i].getBoundingClientRect().left + (draggableElementsA[i].getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) - c2) * level - (draggableElementsA[i].getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) + canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left + "px";
```

The context should be made clear on the [actual file](https://repl.it/@theikp/Map#draw.js). This function performs an odd operation: it moves the units off the screen, far greater than any of the individual measurements. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was just doing something similar and had a he hard time to go through the same agony. Someone pointed out that I should use a GIS library. I looked up for a free one and found leaflet. It took a couple of hours to switch to leaflet. It cut my code by half and got all the bells and whistles out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue arises when scrolling while in the zoomed state. Specifically, zooming in, moving an object, and unzooming results in the item being offset.

When recording the XY coordinates, specifically in these two lines:

```
pos3 = parseInt(e.clientX);
pos4 = parseInt(e.clientY);
```

record the position relative to the top of the game board, not simply the position of the mouse cursor on the screen.